# Shuffle an Array is giving the same value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, random, shuffle

I'm making a generator of random arrays shuffling one initial array multiple times.

**SHUFFLE FUNCTION**

```
const shuffle =(array) => {
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}
```

**GENERATE CHROMOSOMES(This function generates an array of arrays that are randomized from an initial one** "sequence")

```
const generateChromosomes = (numberOfChromosomes) =>{
    const result = [];
    const sequence = ["2", "3", "4"];

    for(let i = 1; i < numberOfChromosomes; i++){
        result.push(shuffle(sequence))
    }

    return(result);
}
```

I do not know why, each time when I run it, I don't get different arrays. I get 50 times the same one. When I re-run the code, it gives me 50 times another one.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, my guess is that this problem is related to the array reference.
Move your sequence array into the loop so you disable the referer and set the shuffle by the static value of the variable.

```
const generateChromosomess = (numberOfChromosomes) => {
    const result = [];

    for(let i = 1; i < numberOfChromosomes; i++){
        const sequence = ["2", "3", "4"]; // MOVE YOUR ARRAY HERE.

        result.push(shuffle(sequence))
    }

    return(result);
}
```

There is few ways to cancel the reference of the array - via

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
```

OR

```
[...value]
```

OR (via `lodash`)

```
_.clone(array)
```

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(anything))` is extremely rarely useful.

Comment: But still safe to use and will support in any browser.

Comment: It's safe unless the array or object contains refernces to objects that `JSON.stringify()` won't touch, like Date instances or functions, or if the source object has circular references.